# Does matched filtering with real samples have a 3dB gain over complex samples?

Tags: matched-filter

I am getting a shocking result from my matched filtering simulations and math.  It would seem unlikely, but I'm seeing a 3dB gain in SNR if I process real samples instead of complex.  Where is the flaw in this reasoning?

A matched filter is a convolution of the received noisy signal with a conjugated reversed copy of the transmitted signal vector.  The noisy real signal at the front end of the receiver is, where $s[n]$ is the signal and $w[n]$ is the noise:
$$\begin{equation}x[n]=s[n]+w[n]\end{equation}$$
The signal to noise ratio is, with $2N$ as the number of real samples in the noisy signal:
$$SNR_r=\frac{P_s}{P_w} =\frac{\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}|s[n]|^2}{\mathbb{E}\{\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}|w[n]|^2\}} =\frac{\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}\mathbb{E}|w[n]|^2}$$
Assuming additive white Gaussian noise (AWGN), $\mathbb{E}|w[n]|^2=\sigma^2$ and the SNR is, with $N_0 = kT_s$:
$$SNR_r=\frac{\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{2N\sigma^2}=\frac{\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{2N\frac{N_0}{2}2B_n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2N}\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{N_0B_n}=\frac{P_s}{P_w}$$
Because x is real, it’s spectrum must be conjugate symmetric, and therefore its power is evenly divided between the positive and negative frequency components.  Upon conversion to complex samples, either the positive or negative frequency components must be filtered away.  Therefore, the complex version of the noisy signal must have half the power of the noisy real signal.
$$P_x=2P_\tilde{x}$$
$$\frac{1}{2N}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}|x[n]|^2 =2 \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|\tilde{x}[n]|^2$$
$$\vec{x}^T\vec{x}=4\tilde{x}^H\tilde{x}$$
However, this affects the signal and noise equally, so the signal to noise ratio is unchanged.  The noise power spectral density is also unchanged, since half the power is distributed over half the bandwidth.  Note that, if this relationship were not true, then the noise power spectral density in the passband would have to double, which cannot be true.  Therefore:
$$SNR_c=\frac{P_\tilde{s}}{P_\tilde{w}} =\frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|\tilde{s}[n]|^2}{\mathbb{E}\{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|\tilde{w}[n]|^2\}} =\frac{\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s}}{\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\mathbb{E}|\tilde{w}[n]|^2}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{4}\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{N\sigma^2}=\frac{\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{4N\frac{N_0}{2}B_n}=\frac{\frac{1}{2N}\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{N_0B_n}$$
and thus:
$$SNR_{in} = SNR_r = SNR_c$$
Keep in mind that the signal and noise are calculated at the front-end of the receiver, and both undergo many stages of amplification, attenuation, and decimation prior to the matched filtering stage.  However, each is affected equally, so the signal to noise ratio is unchanged.  Let us assume that the noisy signal input to the matched filter is therefore a scaled version of that received at the front-end.  With $a$ representing a scaling constant, let the input to the matched filter be:
$$a\tilde{x}[n]=a\tilde{s}[n]+a\tilde{w}[n]$$
The output of the matched filter is, where $\tilde{s}_t^*$ is the transmitted waveform digitized at the same sampling rate as $\tilde{s}$:
$$\tilde{y}[n]=a\tilde{x}[n]*\tilde{s}_t^* [-n]=\tilde{y}_s [n]+\tilde{y}_w [n]=a\tilde{s}[n]*\tilde{s}_t^* [-n]+a\tilde{w}[n]*\tilde{s}_t^*[-n]$$
$\tilde{s}_t^* [n]$ and $\tilde{s}^* [n]$ are related by a constant, which we will call $b$:
$$\frac{\tilde{s}_t^* [n]}{\tilde{s}^* [n]}=b$$
Leading to:
$$y ̃[n]=ab(\tilde{s}[n]*\tilde{s}^* [-n]+w ̃[n]*\tilde{s}^* [-n])$$
The signal portion of the output of the filter is the autocorrelation of $\tilde{s}[n]$:
$$\tilde{s}[n]*\tilde{s}^* [-n]=\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}[n+m] \tilde{s}^* [m]$$
For the maximum SNR, we divide the maximum value of the signal power after filtering by the expectation of the noise power after filtering at that same time.  The maximum value of the filtered instantaneous signal power is:
$$\left(\left(ab\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}[n+m] \tilde{s}^*[m]\right)^2\right)_{max}=\left(ab\left(\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}[n+m] \tilde{s}^* [m]\right)_{max}\right)^2$$
The maximum value of the autocorrelation function always occurs at zero offset:
$$\left(\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}[n+m] \tilde{s}^* [m]\right)_{max}=\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}[m] \tilde{s}^* [m]=\sum_{m=0}^{N-1}|\tilde{s}[m] |^2 =\tilde{s}^H \tilde{s}$$
Note that the maximum value of the signal component output will always be real.  The noise part of the output signal is the cross-correlation of $\tilde{w}[n]$ and $\tilde{s}^* [n]$, but since we know that the signal component will be real, we could simply discard the imaginary component of the noisy signal matched filter output.  In practice, however, this would discard phase information that we need to further process the radar returns.  For example, it would be impossible to process Doppler information without the imaginary component of the output signal.  For now, let us assume that we do not discard the imaginary component of the noisy signal output.

The noise part of the output signal is the cross-correlation of $\tilde{w}[n]$ and $\tilde{s}^* [n]$
$$\tilde{w}[n]*\tilde{s}^* [-n]=\tilde{s}^* [-n]*\tilde{w}[n]=\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}^* [n+m] \tilde{w}[m]$$
At the same time as the peak of the signal power output, the expectation of the output instantaneous noise power is:
$$\mathbb{E}\left\{\left(\left|ab\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}^* [n+m] \tilde{w}[m]\right|^2\right)_{n=0}\right\}=\mathbb{E}\left\{\left|ab\sum_{m=-∞}^{∞}\tilde{s}^* [m] \tilde{w}[m]\right|^2\right\}$$
$$=a^2 b^2 \mathbb{E}\left\{(\tilde{s}^H\tilde{w})^2\right\}=a^2 b^2 \mathbb{E}\left\{(\tilde{s}^H \tilde{w})(\tilde{s}^H \tilde{w})^H \right\}$$
$$=a^2 b^2 \mathbb{E}\left\{\tilde{s}^H \tilde{w}\tilde{w}^H \tilde{s}\right\}=a^2 b^2 \tilde{s}^H \mathbb{E}\left\{\tilde{w}\tilde{w}^H\right\} \tilde{s}=a^2 b^2 \tilde{s}^H \textbf{C}\tilde{s}$$

where $\textbf{C}$ is the covariance matrix of $\tilde{w}$.  Therefore, the maximum SNR is:
$$SNR_{max}=\frac{(\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s})^2}{s ̃^H\textbf{C}\tilde{s}}$$
Under the condition that the noise is AWGN, $\textbf{C}=\sigma^2\textbf{I}$ and the maximum SNR reduces to:
$$SNR_{max}=\frac{(\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s})(\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s})}{\sigma^2 \tilde{s}^H \tilde{s} }=\frac{\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s}}{\sigma^2}$$
The received double-sided noise power spectral density is $\frac{N_0}{2}$ for AWGN.  Under that assumption, $B_n=f_s$.  Therefore,
$$\sigma^2=\frac{N_0}{2} B_n=\frac{N_0}{2} f_s$$
The energy of the received complex signal is:
$$E_\tilde{s} =\frac{1}{f_s} \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}|\tilde{s}[n] |^2=\frac{\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s}}{f_s}$$
Therefore, the output signal to noise ratio maximum is:
$$SNR_{max}=\frac{\tilde{s}^H\tilde{s}}{\sigma^2} =\frac{2E_\tilde{s}f_s}{N_0 f_s}$$
$$\boxed{SNR_{max}=\frac{2E_\tilde{s}}{N_0}}$$
The maximum achievable gain in SNR, the pulse compression gain, is:
$$G_{pc}=\frac{SNR_{max}}{SNR_{in}}=\frac{\frac{2E_\tilde{s}}{N_0}}{\frac{\tilde{s}^H \tilde{s}}{N\sigma^2}}=\frac{2E_\tilde{s}\sigma^2}{N_0 P_\tilde{s}}=\frac{2E_\tilde{s}\frac{B_n}{2}}{\frac{E_\tilde{s}}{\tau}}=B_n \tau$$
Let us consider what the result would be if we used entirely real samples throughout.  The signal and noise lose one half of their energy in the conversion from real to complex, but the noise power spectral density remains unchanged.  This would indicate that there might be a corresponding 3dB increase in the maximum achievable SNR.
Everything in the proof is identical for real and complex samples until one arrives at the calculation of $\sigma^2$, which for real samples becomes:
$$\sigma_r^2=\frac{N_0}{2} 2B_n=\frac{N_0}{2} 2 \frac{f_{s,real}}{2}=\frac{N_0}{2} f_{s,real}$$
where we have assumed that $f_{s,real}=2B_n$, which it must be for our simplifying assumption to be valid.
The energy in the real samples is:
$$E_s=\frac{1}{f_{s,real}}\sum_{n=0}^{2N-1}|s[n]|^2=\frac{\vec{s}^T \vec{s}}{f_{s,real}}$$
Therefore, the same relationship holds:
$$SNR_{max}=\frac{\vec{s}^T\vec{s}}{\sigma_r^2}=\frac{E_s f_{s,real}}{\frac{N_0}{2} f_{s,real}}=\frac{2E_s}{N_0} $$
But, as shown previously,
$$E_s=\frac{\vec{s}^T \vec{s}}{f_{s,real}} =\frac{4s ̃^H s ̃}{2f_s}=\frac{2s ̃^H s ̃}{f_s} =2E_\tilde{s}$$
Therefore, a matched filter with real samples does indeed have a 3dB advantage over a matched filter with complex samples.  The pulse compression gain is:
$$G_{pc}=\frac{SNR_{max}}{SNR_{in}}=\frac{\frac{2E_s}{N_0}}{\frac{\vec{s}^T \vec{s}}{2NN_0 B_n}}=\frac{2E_s B_n}{P_s} =\frac{2E_s B_n}{\frac{E_s}{\tau}}=2B_n\tau$$

To answer the question about how one processes real samples, imagine a bandpass real signal with the following power spectrum:
[image]
Choosing $f_s$ appropriately, after sampling one arrives at the following discrete time Fourier transform (DTFT):
[image]
I've intentionally left this signal oversampled so as to illustrate better what's going on.  One could process this signal as entirely real, but the data rate is higher than necessary, and the noise isn't white any longer either.
Instead, let us first mix the signal to an IF so as to better filter the noise.
[image]
That allows us to choose an optimal $f_s = 2B_n$, resulting in the following DTFT:
[image]
This signal is now real, baseband, and critically sampled (2 times the rate of the complex signal) and can be processed by the matched filter and no phase information has been lost.

Comment: I don't follow how you can make the assumption of using real throughout for the case that phase is important; wouldn't the matched filter need to be a complex output (as a complex baseband signal)? It is clear for the case of a real signal where phase is not part of the information that we can, once we remove the phase offset due to carrier mismatch, eliminate the imaginary term and cut the noise by half, but this is not the case for generalized phase and amplitude modulated signals.

Comment: I'm not following your reasoning.  If you have real samples at the correct sampling rate (twice the complex rate), then you do have the phase information.

Comment: For a complex baseband waveform, phase is a rotation on the complex plane; this can be represented in a real passband waveform, relative to a carrier - is that what you are referring to?

Comment: If we have real baseband samples at the proper sampling rate, the complex signal can always be recovered.  No phase information is lost.

Comment: You can't have a real baseband signal (which extends across DC to the positive and negative frequencies with Hermitian symmetry) and still have the complex information, you can only get this with a real passband signal, right? To represent the information of both magnitude and phase in a signal at baseband, the signal must be complex. We can  alternate between the real and imaginary samples at twice the sampling rate but that is just sample encoding of the complex waveform.

Comment: A direct example is "DC" in the baseband waveform represents the carrier frequency-- how do you represent the phase of this without the waveform being complex?  We can represent complex baseband signals with real passband signals - is that what you intended to say?

Comment: If you have real samples, that means that you have a conjugate symmetric spectrum. To extract the complex signal from that real signal, one simply multiplies times a complex exponential to shift the spectrum to base band, then low pass filters to remove one of the two symmetric side bands.  Or, one can use a Hilbert transform to extract the analytic signal from the real signal.

Comment: I have a carrier at 1 GHz with 45 degrees of phase, I shift it to baseband, so now that carrier is at DC (that is what the "baseband signal is, DC becomes  the frequency of the carrier).  If I have a complex baseband signal, I can recover the 45 degrees  (I+jQ) with I and Q equal. If it is real, we only have "I" and there is no phase.  We can only maintain phase with a passband signal, for instance if we use a low IF, but the IF must be higher than than the bandwidth of the signal at RF to maintain phase.

Comment: You can’t actually do that unless you use quadrature(I/Q) sampling, because otherwise the positive and negative side bands overlap at baseband.  You have to leave the carrier modulated such that the lower frequency of the passband is near DC.  I’ll add some diagrams later.

Comment: Yes, you can move a real signal to a complex baseband: $2\cos(\omega t+\theta) e^{-j\omega t} = e^{j\theta} + e^{-j2\omega t + \theta}$ and low pass filter to get $e^{j\theta}$, right? Thanks for the diagrams. I have to leave but may be good to actually chat later when we're both on. Let me digest your diagram first and thanks for the good question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144948/discussion-between-jonathan-williams-and-dan-boschen).

Comment: oh dear, somebody's gonna make me think